# Android - use spinner default drop shadow

Tags: android, styles, android-spinner, android-popupwindow

I've created my own android drop down list (spinner). Its custom made by using a popupWindow(...).  Now i would like to style it accordingly.  I'd like to apply the same styles that a spinner drop down has or even another kind of drop down.  Im especially in need of shadow effects and drop shadows that show up after the native spinner is rendered.

Anyone know of a style i can apply to get this without building my own drop shadow which might not be identical to the native set ?

Answer (score 7):

found one that works the way i want.  Seems it puts a drop shadow similar to an alert dialog:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```